# Docker child image not overwritting the ENV value of Parent

Tags: java, docker

I have a child image where I'm defining

```
 ARG MX_HEAP_SET=1024
    ARG MN_HEAP_SET=1024
    ENV MX_HEAP_SET=${MX_HEAP_SET:-${MX_HEAP_SET}}
    ENV MN_HEAP_SET=${MN_HEAP_SET:-${MN_HEAP_SET}}
    ENV HEAP_SET="-Xmx${MX_HEAP_SET}m -Xms${MN_HEAP_SET}m"
    ENV HEAP_SET=${HEAP_SET:-${HEAP_SET}}
```

and expecting to replace the default value of `HEAP_SET` which is placed in base image.
So, when I run the base image without any MX or MN value, then it works fine.

However as soon as I run the child image with `docker run -e  MX_HEAP_SET=2048`, I still see the default value in container.

But as soon as I run d`ocker run -e HEAP_SET="-Xmx2048m -Xms1024m"` i see the change. 
So, how can I implement same behavior with individual MAX and MIN parameters not as a string?

Is there other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use below

```
ARG MX_HEAP_SET=1024
```

It means you are adding a build time argument. This can be overridden only during the docker build. What you need is rather startup bash file

*/app/start.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# export all variables from here on
set -a

MX_HEAP_SET=${MX_HEAP_SET:-1024}
MN_HEAP_SET=${MN_HEAP_SET:-1024}
MX_HEAP_SET=${SDC_MX_HEAP_SET:-${MX_HEAP_SET}}
MN_HEAP_SET=${SDC_MN_HEAP_SET:-${MN_HEAP_SET}}
HEAP_SET="-Xmx${MX_HEAP_SET}m -Xms${MN_HEAP_SET}m"
HEAP_SET=${HEAP_SET:-${HEAP_SET}}
exec "<yourstarting command>" $@
```

This will respect the environment variables the you give while running the image itself

But you need to make sure override your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to run `/app/start.sh`

`exec` is used in the end to make sure the running program replaces the shell process with itself

Comment: I know, that ARG will be passed during build time, that's why the next line I tried to export the same as ENV variable if nothing passed during the runtime as `-e`. I will see if this start.sh will be working or not.

Comment: ENV also is a build time statement only